# Add a button to end of check box after sucees of ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jqgrid

I have a separate button outside the jqGrid when I click on this button I need to add a custom button nearr to  the selected checkbox

So far I am getting the check box ids but not getting how to add an icon to the selected checkboxes

```
$('.lock').click(function() {
    //var grid_selector_second = "#grid-table";
    var grid = jQuery("#grid-table");
    var str = '';
    var i;
       var data = grid.getRowData();
       for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
           //alert(data[i]);jqg_grid-table_8092415
           //jqg_grid-table_8089033

            if(data[i].checkbox==='Yes')
                str += data[i].id+',';
       }
       alert(str);

});
```

**Update**

I have following html (say 3 rows from jqgrid ).When I click on a button I am doing some ajax call and passing ids to server,these ids are from tr (,this can be seen in the below html).I am returing some ids from server to client .

For eg: I am sending 8089033,8089034,8049033 as ids and on success I send only 8089033,8089034 from server.I need to add an icon to end of the checkbox.This  can be added to only suceess ids row. I use

```
<tr class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" tabindex="-1" id="8089033" role="row">
<td aria-describedby="grid-table_cb" style="text-align:center;width: 25px;" role="gridcell"></td>
<td>.....<td>

<td aria-describedby="grid-table_checkbox" title="" style="" role="gridcell">
<input type="checkbox" offval="no" value=""></td></tr>

//second row

<tr class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" tabindex="-1" id="8089034" role="row">
<td aria-describedby="grid-table_cb" style="text-align:center;width: 25px;" role="gridcell"></td>
<td>.....<td>

<td aria-describedby="grid-table_checkbox" title="" style="" role="gridcell">
<input type="checkbox" offval="no" value=""></td></tr>
//third row

<tr class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" tabindex="-1" id="8049033" role="row">
<td aria-describedby="grid-table_cb" style="text-align:center;width: 25px;" role="gridcell"></td>
<td>.....<td>

<td aria-describedby="grid-table_checkbox" title="" style="" role="gridcell">
<input type="checkbox" offval="no" value=""></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This jQuery selector will add an image after all checked checkboxes in the grid:

```
$("#grid-table input[type=checkbox]:checked")
  .after($("<img src='tick.png'>"));
```

You'll have to refine the selector if you want to exclude certain checkboxes, e.g. in other columns.

**UPDATE** for additional requirements:

I'm assuming you get the return ID's from the server as JSON data in an array, e.g.:

```
var result = [8089033, 8089034];    //will be set by ajax call

$.map(result, function (id) {
    $("#grid-table tr#" + id)
        .find("input[type=checkbox]")
        .after($("<img src='http://www.placehold.it/20x10/ff0000'>"));
    });
});
```

Note this is not checking if the checkboxes in the rows denoted by the returned ID's are checked or not - it is assumed that the set of ID's returned is a subset of the original set (which were all :checked).

If you need to check again if they are checked, then simply change to:

```
.find("input[type=checkbox]:checked")
```

Comment: I have marked as correct but i wanted to do something different I am again posting new question

Comment: Actualy we check with ids,Is it necessary to add .find("input[type=checkbox]:checked").I don't understand that part.I it possible to use addClass() instead of  img src ?

Comment: No, you can ignore the last code snippet. It is only if you need to check *again* after the AJAX call to see if the checkboxes are checked or not. But it's not really necessary.

Comment: thanks.I am able to see ,you have used img. is it possible to use addClass() instead of img src ?

Comment: Of course. If you want to add the class to the checkbox inputs then use `.find("input[type='checkbox']").addClass("my-class")` and remove the `.after(..)`, but if you want to add the class to the TD which contains the checkbox do `.find("input[type='checkbox']").parent().addClass("my-class")`

Comment: I am getting following php array Array
(
    [0] => 8092415
    [1] => 8097941
) and its not working

Comment: TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a. this is the error i am getting. I have given [2121] to test.Still getting the typeError

Comment: this is the one I am getting after json encode but still not working   {"ignored":[],"status":{"message":"success","code":200},"locked":[8089033,8092415]}

Comment: I'll consider this question closed. Please ask a new question if you're still having problems. Good luck!